# Hide a page in default language (but show it in alternative languages)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I setup a Typo3 7.6 with multilanguage and I need to be able to hide some pages in default language, but show it in alternative languages.

The problem is, when I hide the page in the default languages, all other languages are hidden too. Or, when I am logged in, I get the PREVIEW Info, in all languages.

The other way around, hiding a alternative language, works fine and I can still access the default language.

This is my typoscript:

```
config {
  htmlTag_langKey = en
  sys_language_uid = 0
  language = en
  locale_all = en_EN
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_mode = strict
}


[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config {
  htmlTag_langKey = 1
  sys_language_uid = 1
  language = de
  locale_all = de_CH
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_mode = strict
}
```

So is it possible to hide the default language in typo3 7.6? The alternative would be to use a dummy-default-language and use the current default language as an alternative language too.

Comment: you donot need to hide page, make a condition in your menu with exclude pages when default language condition match. but one question in my mind how will you go other language pages when you exclude pages from your menu?

Comment: @GhanshyamGohel It is to hide some pages in default language, not all. And its important that editors can do it themselfes. So typoscript solutions arnt good

Answer (score 4):

Just **edit the page record**, go to the **behaviour tab**. Under Language Localization you will find the option: **hide default translation of page**.